# Using my own sort to sort 2D vertices clockwise

Tags: c++

So I have a vector of vertices I'm trying to sort and I'm new to using predicates. This is what I current do to sort my vertices.

```
void Triangulate::OrderVertices()
{
     std::sort(mVertices.begin(), mVertices.end(), Triangulate::ClockWise());
}
```

And this is my sorting predicate

```
bool Triangulate::ClockWise::operator()(const CVertex2& pointA, const CVertex2& pointB)
{
    if(pointA.mPoint.x >= 0 && pointB.mPoint.x < 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if(pointA.mPoint.x == 0 &&  pointB.mPoint.x == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

        // Gets the center of my current viewport
    CVertex2 centerCoordinate(CClipper::Instance()->GetMidX(), CClipper::Instance()->GetMidY());


    // compute the cross product of vectors
    int det = (int)((pointA.mPoint.x - centerCoordinate.mPoint.x) * 
                    (pointB.mPoint.y - centerCoordinate.mPoint.y) - 
                    (pointB.mPoint.x - centerCoordinate.mPoint.x) *
                    (pointA.mPoint.y - centerCoordinate.mPoint.y));

    if(det < 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if(det > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int det1 = (int)((pointA.mPoint.x - centerCoordinate.mPoint.x) * 
                        (pointA.mPoint.x - centerCoordinate.mPoint.x) + 
                        (pointA.mPoint.y - centerCoordinate.mPoint.y) * 
                        (pointA.mPoint.y - centerCoordinate.mPoint.y));

    int det2 = (int)((pointB.mPoint.x - centerCoordinate.mPoint.x) *
                        (pointB.mPoint.x - centerCoordinate.mPoint.x) +
                        (pointB.mPoint.y - centerCoordinate.mPoint.y) *
                        (pointB.mPoint.y - centerCoordinate.mPoint.y));

    return det1 > det2;
}
```

I currently have my predicate set up within my triangulate class like so.

```
class Triangulate
{
    friend class ClockWise;
public:

    Triangulate(std::vector<CVertex2>& vertices)
        :mVertices(vertices) {}
    ~Triangulate(void);

    class ClockWise
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(const CVertex2& pointA, const CVertex2& pointB);
    };

private:
};
```

When I get an error and I'm pretty sure it is because I didn't set this up right. Can someone help?

Comment: What kind of error? Be more specific.

Comment: Probably  easier to use `atan2` than implement it all on your own.

Comment: `if(pointA.mPoint.x == 0 &&  pointB.mPoint.x == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }`
This violates the strict weak ordering requirements. For two vertices with `x == 0`, you have `A < B` and `B < A` hold simultaneously.

Comment: chris: I get operator< is invalid

JerryCoffin: How would I use that to sort my vertices?

IgorTandetnik: My bad, it was suppose to return pointA.mPoint.y > pointB.mPoint.x

Comment: @user1527216, Post the complete error message and the line on which it occurs. An SSCCE would be even better.

Comment: @user1527216: `atan2` gives you an angle from 0 to 2pi, starting from directly to the right as 0 and going  counterclockwise. You basically need to reverse the direction and possibly adjust the origin (to straight up?)

Comment: Shouldn't the predicate passed to `std::sort()` be `Triangulate::ClockWise` rather than `Triangulate::ClockWise()`?

Comment: @Jonathan Potter [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) takes a class instance as the last parameter.

Comment: I think the tittle starting with ***Using my own...*** is a bad first impression... The question is auto-answered: **Don't use your own, use a bug-free and tested implementation like `std::sort`**